# pointer to struct in function prototype before defining struct

Tags: c

I am trying to create a struct that I will use in a function via pointers. The issue is that I do not want to use global variables therefore I can't use a pointer to a struct as a parameter for the function prototype if I try to define the struct in main file, since it has not been defined yet.

How would I go about doing this? What I think the solution is, is to define the struct in a header file, then create local variables of that type in the main file. Is this the right way to go about this? Would appreciate some info about what i'm actually doing here if this is correct.

Sorry if I did anything wrong when posting, Its my first time.

Example of what I am thinking the solution is

Main.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
                  
typedef struct Vehicle{
int a;
char b;
};
function(Vehicle *p);
```

Main.c

```
#include "Main.h"

Vehicle Car1;
Vehicle *p=&Car1; 
function(p);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I do not want to use global variables therefore I can't use a pointer to a struct as a parameter for the function prototype if I try to define the struct in main file, since it has not been defined yet." First of all, this has nothing to do with using global variables, and secondly, you can define the struct and then use it as a parameter for a function prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax for a typedef is

```
typedef T-IDENTIFIER IDENTIFIER-LIST;
```

wherein the comma separated identifiers listed in IDENTIFIER-LIST become *aliases* for T-IDENTIFIER. A lot of the time IDENTIFIER-LIST will consist of a single identifier.

For example, in

```
typedef int integer, number;
```

`integer` and `number` are now type aliases for `int`.

When it comes to using `typedef` with structs, the form

```
typedef struct foo { /* ... */ } foo_type;
```

is more or less shorthand for

```
typedef struct foo foo_type;
struct foo { /* ... */ };
```

but does allow you to `typedef` an *anonymous struct*

```
typedef struct { /* ... */ } foo_type;
```

With all that said, in your code you have omitted the IDENTIFIER-LIST from your `typedef`.

---

If `main.c` really does consist entirely of the code you've posted, it will not compile. Every C program needs an *entry point*, and in a *hosted environment* that is the function `main` with the signature `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

While you can declare variables outside of functions (i.e., globals), you can not call functions from outside of functions. Everything starts from `main`.

A working example program:

`main.h`:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    char b;
} Vehicle;     
                          
void function(Vehicle *p);
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

int main(void) {
    Vehicle car = { 51, 'A' };

    function(&car);
}

void function(Vehicle *v) {
    printf("Vehicle: a: %d, b: %c\n", v->a, v->b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use the struct as a parameter for the function prototype

You misunderstood something.

1. Your typedef is rather useless.
2. You of course can use pointers to structs as function parameters and in the function prototypes.

```
typedef struct {
int a;
char b;
} Vehicle;


int foo(Vehicle *);  // prototype
```

You can't call function not outside other functions (as it is shown in the `main.c`

Comment: Oh I missed some things when typing the questions, I knew what I could use pointers as a parameters and that I missed writing the prototype so edited it to fix it and reformulated the question to be easier to understand. Also why is the typdef useless? I don't need to write struct anymore right?

Comment: @Speedyspeedboy, gasoline's burnin'. uh, I mean 0 is referring to the the fact that you didn't give the typedef a name. See the difference between what you wrote and what they wrote.

Comment: @Speedyspeedboy it is easy to understand. Compare the versions of the typedefs and spot the difference. .